# Drag over element motion

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I am developing a phonegap/cordova application and I need info on a specific topic. Is there a Javascript library  to track touch gestures and capture when element are touched during the gesture es in the picture below?

[image]

The green line would be the gesture over the screen and the red circle would be the div elements catching that the gesture was drawn over them.